# Unable to install grub-customizer on Manjaro 21.0.4

Tags: archlinux, manjaro, grub, pacman-package-manager

I'm having trouble installing other packages too, I assume it's because I didn't configure something. Thoughts?

```sh
sudo pacman -S grub-customizer
                                        
error: target not found: grub-customizer
```

Comment: I wonder why it doesn't exist in manjaro repos

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Download the offline installer of the application in this link: https://archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/grub-customizer/download/
Then double click on it in Dolphin and that's it.